# Efficiently load large JSON file into SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server

I have been attempting to identify what the most effective way to load a large JSON file into SQL Server is.

I have a rather primitive API that most helpfully returns me a 150+ MB JSON string with ~450k rows and 12 columns. Ultimately I want to be able to use this in power-query, I figure the simplest way to store, index, then query it efficiently will be in SQL Server.

I have asked regarding filtering the data from the source (the most logical solution, but for the purposes of this question, count it out).

I have attempted code like the following to prove it will work

```
DECLARE @JSON VARCHAR(MAX)

select @JSON = BulkColumn
from OPENROWSET 
(BULK 'C:\temp\test.txt', SINGLE_CLOB) 
AS j

Select * FROM OPENJSON (@JSON)
```

The issue I have is that after 7 minutes query time on a laptop with fast SSD, 16gb ram and i7-7800hq I decided there must be a better way of going about this.

I'm happy to try any other language (say python, r, C# clr)

Security isn't my primary concern, I think I should be able to refresh the data in a few seconds rather than waiting several minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never used to encounter problems loading significant volumes (several hundreds of megabytes of json) in, simply a query variable from the C# app I wrote to load these files.. The load also included a query that only inserted records that didn't already exist.

```
INSERT dba.dbo.Table(columns,from,json)
FROM 
    OPENJSON (@json, '$.result' )  
    WITH (   
        column varchar(256) '$.a',
        from varchar(256) '$.b',
        json varchar(256) '$.c'
     ) j

     LEFT JOIN dba.dbo.Table b
     ON
       j.column = b.column
WHERE
    b.column IS NULL
```

Something like this would take around 30 seconds to load 100mb of json and insert only the new records. The c# looked like:

```
            using (SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("...", new SqlConnection(_connstr)))
            {
                sc.Parameters.Add("@json", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1).Value = json;

                var prior = sc.Connection.State;
                if (sc.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    sc.Connection.Open();

                int ins = sc.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (prior == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    sc.Connection.Close();

                return ins;
            }
```

Critically, I seldom needed to do what you're doing (retrieve all the rows back as a SSMS result set or whatever). I would do the load, then do the work I needed with them. An appreciable proportion of the time you're waiting might be down to SSMS retrieving millions of rows

Comment: Thanks. I thought since I might have locked down sql memory allowances, so I'll check that. And yeah, be interested if loading data into tables is faster than into a query results window..? I still think 7mins is way to long for sql to parse and return the json

Comment: I would say it is quite long. I was working with a server whose spec was a couple of notches above normal but I expect that the majority of the time was spent joining the inbound data to the existing

Comment: Found my issue mostly related to trying to return the entire json string into one field... There was metadata {...}, Value {...}. As soon as I got openjson to parse the data properly my query time dropped to ~12-14s

Answer (score 0):

ADO.NET SqlClient has the ability to stream data into and out of a binary/varbinary (stream object) or char/nchar/nvarchar/xml (text reader object) SQL table column (the reference document is here: [SqlClient Streaming Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sqlclient-streaming-support#streaming-support-to-sql-server)).

Streaming has a much lower memory footprint especially for large documents and there's less chance of messing with structure of the actual document being stored in SQL since the stream can come directly from the source, e.g. a HTTP response content stream, without being read by another kind of reader, e.g. JsonReader.

The code is similar to the answer by Caius Jard, except that the "json" variable needs to be a TextReader derived type.

Therefore, you can pass a stream then wrap that with say a StreamReader and finally set that as the command parameter value.

```
using var textReader = new StreamReader(json);
sc.Parameters.Add("@json", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1).Value = textReader;
```